# Which Object onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, this

For the HTML below, what is the best centralized way to replace using an inline onclick in each of the five siblings's children DIVs to set the background color red for whichever one gets clicked and clearing all others?

The inline approach to be replaced:

```
<div id="tab1" onclick="setRed();">tab 1</div>
```

Leaving cleaner markup:

```
<div>tab 1</div>
```

This is how the whole thing should look:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="blue"><div>tab 1</div></div>
    <div class="blue"><div>tab 2</div></div>
    <div class="blue"><div>tab 3</div></div>
    <div class="blue"><div>tab 4</div></div>
    <div class="blue"><div>tab 5</div></div>
</div>
```

This is the final solution, hobbling the select portion from user2865156 and adding some javascript to clear the rest:

```
$("#nav div div").on('click', function () {
    if (this.style.backgroundColor !== "red") {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "red";

        siblingDivs = this.parentNode.parentNode.children;
        for (var i = 0; i < siblingDivs.length; i++) {
            if (this !== siblingDivs[i].children[0]) {
                siblingDivs[i].children[0].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/8100df2b90bfd959b050d48bcd3f9482)

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 24px;
}
.blue {
  cursor: default;
  border: 1px dashed #454545;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.blue.active {
  background: red;
}
```

jquery js

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav').on('click', '.blue', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            innerHtml = $this.html(), //inner html
            text = $this.text();

        // there are obv easier ways to do the below; just a proof of concept.
        !!~text.indexOf("tab") && $('.active').removeClass('active') && 
            $this.addClass('active');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this. You need to set it to the actual function instead of the value of the return value:

```
var divTabs = document.getElementById("nav").onclick = function() {
    //do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, you may need to use the `.each()` method to get the *index* of the clicked element and add the corresponding `red` class to it, so

having this css

```
.red { background-color: #ff0000; }
```

You could use this jQuery script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".blue").each(function (i) {
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            $(".blue").removeClass("red").eq(i).addClass("red")
        })
    })
}); // ready
```

**Notice** we are using the `.eq(i)` method to assign the `red` *class* to the clicked element after removing the same *class* from any other.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5pjtnqm3/)**

Comment: Excellent. I never completed my thoughts in my scenario, but yes, the idea was to indicate the selected sibling. Your solution is over my newbie head, so now I'm digging up how removeClass("red").eq(i) is removing the red class from the other siblings, while "this" sibling gets red added with .addClass("red"). Thank you!

Comment: I commented "..removeClass("red").eq(i)  is removing the red.." Did I get that wrong? Is it actually eq(i).addClass("red") that is getting the red class added, based on the index i of this?

Comment: This `$(".blue").removeClass("red").eq(i).addClass("red")` removes the *class* `red` from all selectors with *class* `blue` but add the *class* `red` only to the element that matches the value of `i` (you get the value of `i` from the clicked elements within the `each()` method)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, target the class:

```
$("#nav .blue").click(function() {
    //$(this) refers to the clicked element as a jQuery object
    var innerHtml = $(this).html(); //inner html
    var text = $(this).text(); //text inside the inner html

    //Logic
});
```

Comment: $("#nav .blue") is the parent, right? Isn't there still a .children[0] to target for each $("#nav .blue")? (Still learning this stuff - sorry if I'm missing something.)

Comment: `#nav` is the parent, and `.blue` is a child of `#nav` - not sure what you're looking for with the `children[0]` @Guessed

Comment: Each .blue DIV also has its own nested child DIV (overkill, I know, but needed for other formatting reasons not mentioned, to simplify the discussion). Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/Lwex5wr4/

```
$(".blue").on('click', function() {
  if (this.style.backgroundColor === "red") {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "transparent"; 
  } else {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red"; 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
$("#nav .blue").click(function() {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```